# $R/A$ is a field if and only if $A$ is maximal

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Notation: $R/A$ is a factor ring.

I am having a problem understanding the final part of the textbook proof. It refers to an exercise in the textbook that I am unsure how it applies.
I understand the other direction so I will only include the one direction I do not understand. Thank you for your time. Note that the proof below is my interpretation.

Proof: $R/A$ is a field $\Rightarrow$ $A$ is maximal

Suppose $R/A$ is a field, $B$ is an ideal of $R$ such that $A \subseteq B \subseteq R$

Let $\alpha \in B$ and $\alpha \not\in A$. Then $\alpha+A$ is a non zero element of $R/A$ since $$\alpha \not\in A \ \therefore \exists \beta \in A : (\alpha+A)(\beta + B) = \alpha\beta + A = 1 + A$$ (since $R/A$ is a field (multiplicative inverse)).

Since $A \subseteq B \subseteq R$, and $\alpha \in B$, then $\alpha\beta \in B$ since $$1 + A = \alpha\beta + A \Rightarrow 1-\alpha\beta \in A \subset B$$

So $$(1 + \alpha\beta) - \alpha\beta + B \Rightarrow 1 \in B$$

Hence $B = R$

This proves $A$ is maximal

I dont understand the last part of the prove. Since $\beta \in A$, and $A \subseteq B$, and $\alpha \in A$, then doesnt $\alpha\beta + B = 0? $ And from my understanding, maximal means if $A,B$ are ideals of $R$ such that $A \subseteq B \subseteq R$, then $A = B$ or $B = R$, what approach would we take to show $A = B$ ? I don't think its sufficent to show one part of the or statement. Thank you again

Comment: By taking $\alpha\in B,\alpha\not\in A$ we are _assuming_ that $A\neq B$, and from there we deduce $B=R$.

Comment: You are essentially proving the 'or' statement  $B=A$ or $B=R$.  The standard way to prove $p$ or $q$ is assume $p$ is false then prove $q$ is true (or vice versa).  So are you asking how to prove if $B \neq R$, then $B=A$?

Comment: Thanks @JonathanBrown that was a silly question.

Comment: @Wojowu Yes but if I recall correctly (havent done set theory in a while), that proper subsets mean that $B$ has an additional element over $A$. Then what ever is in $A$ is in $B$, but not vice versa. So if $\beta$ is in $A$, then it must be in $B$

Comment: Exactly. We are taking $\alpha$ to be such an additional element which is in $B$ but not in $A$.

Comment: @Wojowu Sorry I ment $\beta$

Comment: It doesn't matter whether $\beta$ is in either $B$ or $A$ or not. It only matters that $\alpha\beta$ is.